# Magento 2 - Data Migration needs to ignore a custom table

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, database, data-migration, delta-migration

Need to ignore a table from data migration, the table name is "store" where its a default table in Magento 2.

Even updated the map.xml to ignore the store table by below code under **document_rules** block but it's unsuccessful and store table still migrated.

```
<ignore>
   <document>store*</document>
</ignore>
```

The below command I use for the data migration.

> bin/magento migrate:data -a
>   vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.0.1/config.xml

Is there any solution to avoid adding during the data migration?

Comment: Can anyone help me to sort out this?

Comment: You write above code in `source` or `destination` ?

Comment: Placed on the **source** tag, need to place on the **destination** tag?